# hadoop issue in installation and configuration

Tags: hadoop

After installing hadoop when I am trying to start start-dfs.sh it is showing following error message.

I have searched a lot and found that WARN is because I am using 
UBUNTU 64bit OS and hadoop is compiled against 32bit.
So its not an issue to work on.

But the Incorrect configuration is something I am worried about. And also not able to start the primary and secondary namenodes.

```
sameer@sameer-Compaq-610:~$ start-dfs.sh
15/07/27 07:47:41 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
Starting namenodes on []
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: ssh: connect to host 0.0.0.0 port 22: Connection refused**
15/07/27 07:47:56 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

My current configuration:
    hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>

 <property>
   <name>dfs.replication</name>
   <value>1</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
   <value>file:/home/sameer/mydata/hdfs/namenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>file:/home/sameer/mydata/hdfs/datanode</value>
 </property>

</configuration>

core-site.xml
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>fs.default.name </name>
      <value> hdfs://localhost:9000 </value> 
   </property>
</configuration>

yarn-site.xml
<configuration>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
   <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
      <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value> 
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
   </property>
</configuration>

mapred-site.xml

<configuration>
   <property> 
      <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
      <value>yarn</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

Please find what I am doing wrong in configuration or somewhere else.?

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 2):

One problem is a space in your core-site.xml configuration. Remove the leading and trailing space in fs.default.name property.

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>fs.default.name</name>
      <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value> 
   </property>
</configuration>
```

Another problem is ssh service is not running in your machine. This is not a necessary service. The start-all.sh, stop-all.sh, start-dfs.sh etc scripts needs ssh. So better to install that. You can install and start open-ssh server with the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

Then check whether the service is running or not. if it is running, the following command returns some result.

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 22
```

An alternative to start hadoop without ssh is by using ***hadoop-daemon.sh start [daemon-name]***

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need yo install openssh server. Hope this link will help:

https://sites.google.com/site/randomt3ch/home/connect-to-host-localhost-port-22-connection-refused